# Why $(2n+2)! ≥ (n+2)! (n+2)^n$ is true?

Tags: inequality, factorial

How to proof or transform this inequality to be true?

$$(2n+2)! ≥ (n+2)! (n+2)^n$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$(2n+2)!=\overbrace{(2n+2)(2n+1)\dots(n+3)}^{\text{n terms}}(n+2)!$$